# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ExampleID'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Upon executing I keep receiving the error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ExampleID', table
>   'DB_Example.dbo.tbl_Example'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.

However I don't think any NULL values are present. I am trying to simply fill a table with specific values by using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Example
INSERT INTO tbl_Example ([Name])
VALUES ('Example1'),
('Example2'),
('Example3'), 
('Example4')
```

I am using the exact same code/format to fill 3 other tables in the database and do not receive an error for any of them besides this one. Cannot figure it out.

Edit: DBMS is SQL Server

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: What are the columns those are in tbl_Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that columns not included in the `INSERT` are set to their default values.  The default "default" is `NULL`, which is why you are getting your error.

Check your definition of `Example`.  Normally, a column called `ExampleId` would be an identity column.  So, it should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Example (
    ExampleId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(?)
);
```

The `IDENTITY()` serves as a default value.  It is a generally increasing sequence of values, based on insertion order.

With this definition, your code will work:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Example ([Name])
VALUES ('Example1'),
       ('Example2'),
       ('Example3'), 
       ('Example4');
```

I would not recommend explicitly inserting the values of a primary key.  There are some situations where you want to do that, but as a general rule, automatically generating keys is preferable (if you want to avoid errors on inserts).

Comment: This worked. Table design wasn't done correctly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Seems `tbl_Example` has other column (i.e. `ExampleID`) that has `NOT NULL` constraint defined. So, you can't insert null values :

You need to state that column also :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Example (ExampleID, [Name])
     VALUES (?, 'Example1'), (?, 'Example2'), (?, 'Example3'), (?, 'Example4')
```

Whenever you use `INSERT INTO table (column_list)` statement & if any columns that have defined the `NOT NULL` constraint then you must need to state that column name expect identity column such as `primary key`.

For instance, your `ExampleID` column suggests me to as identity column.